# Is it possible to 'concat' two different COUNT(column) WHERE column can have two differen values and different total?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I come with this problem in a kinda complex query to me. Let me be more clear with an example.

If I have a banner table which stores all the banners on a site and I have another table called banner_statistics which stores a record for each banner event in a particular period of time (the event can be 'I', which means an impression of the banner and 'C', which means a click on a banner).

If I run this query:

```
-- Count number of impressions of the banner with id = 1
SELECT 
    ban_id,
    ban_url,
    COUNT(bansta_event) as num_impressions
FROM banner
    LEFT JOIN banner_statistics
        ON bansta_ban_id = ban_id
        AND bansta_event = 'I' 
WHERE ban_id = 1
```

I get:

```
ban_id    ban_url                    num_impressions
1         http://www.cocacola.com    7
```

It says that the banner with id = 1 which is a cocacola banner had a total of 7 impressions.

If I run the same query with the 'C' (click event on that banner):

```
-- Count number of impressions of the banner with id = 1
SELECT 
    ban_id,
    ban_url,
    COUNT(bansta_event) as num_impressions
FROM banner
    LEFT JOIN banner_statistics
        ON bansta_ban_id = ban_id
        AND bansta_event = 'C' 
WHERE ban_id = 1
```

I get:

```
ban_id    ban_url                    num_clicks
 1        http://www.cocacola.com    1
```

It says that this banner had only one click

Now how can I merge those results into a single query in order to obtain this result:

```
ban_id    ban_url                    num_impressions     num_clicks
1         http://www.cocacola.com    7                   1
```

Is there a way to do it? It seems like a CONCAT but it's not cause it is the result of another query with a COUNT on the same column but where the condition on what to count on that column is different...

How can I achieve this in MySQL? I have found that there is GROUP_CONCAT but it can't receive the result of a SELECT query as param, and I don't think that it can work in my case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ban_id,
    ban_url,
    IFNULL(SUM(bansta_event = 'C'), 0) as num_impressions,
    IFNULL(SUM(bansta_event = 'I'), 0) as num_clicks
FROM banner
LEFT JOIN banner_statistics
    ON bansta_ban_id = ban_id
        AND bansta_event IN ('I', 'C') 
WHERE ban_id = 1
```

In MySQL, comparison operators return `1` when they match, `0` when they don't. So summing them gets the count of rows that match that criteria. The `IFNULL` is needed in case there are no rows that match that the criteria, so we get `0` instead of `NULL` in the results.

Comment: Beautiful! Could you explain me please how and why it works? Thank you!

Comment: Added some explanation to the answer

Comment: Thank you, so this can work even if I omit the WHERE clause and add a **GROUP BY ban_id** in order to get a statistic info of the number of clicks and impressions of each banner stored in the banner table, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's an extremely common way to use this.